# Integrating WinJS with a ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, bower, winjs

I'm trying to integrate [**WinJS**](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#tooltip:basics) with an ASP.NET MVC6 application created with the recent Visual Studio 2015 and display a tooltip for a link. But it does not work.

The output should look like:

[image]

Here is how different parts of the app look like:

**bower.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "0.8.0",
    "hammer.js": "2.0.4",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.11.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2",
    "winjs": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

There is **no change in gulpfile.js**.

Added these to the **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/winjs/css/ui-light.css" />
<script src="~/lib/winjs/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/winjs/js/ui.js"></script>
```

My html code is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Tooltip"
         data-win-options="{innerHTML: 'Microsoft Corporation<br><span class=\'win-text-domain\'>www.microsoft.com</span>'}"
         style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom:30px">
        <span class="win-link">Microsoft</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**wwwroot\js\site.js** has

```
// Write your Javascript code.

WinJS.UI.processAll();
```

[image: winjs]

Comment: Are both ui.js and base.js in the lib folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code in **site.js**.

```
(function () {
    WinJS.UI.processAll();
})();
```

Then included the site.js as part of the **Development** environment.

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/hammer.js/hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/js/bootstrap-touch-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/winjs/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/winjs/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-file-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```